# Regex that matches a specific word between tags

Tags: regex, xml

I need a regex that matches a specific word inside tags of XML

```
<t1:ExecuteTask DisplayName="Normes" Task="932en283" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" Parameter="Normes tares" Value="[NormeTare]">
                  <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                    <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
                  </scg:Dictionary>
              </t1:ExecuteTask>
              ...
                  <t1:ReadProductParameterValue DisplayName="Normes volumes" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" Parameter="Normes volumes" Value="[NormeVol]">

                  </t1:ReadProductParameterValue>
```

Here I'm looking for the regex that'll match Task but only inside the tags   So I can replace it by another word..
This is the regex I made so far `<t[1-2]:ExecuteTask(.*?)>`

Comment: No, what you need is a parser and a more descriptive question (tool? language you're using?)

Comment: I'm using VB.NET I'm trying to match exactly only the word Task so I can replace it by TaskID using this: 
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(MyText, "<t[1-2]:ExecuteTask(.*?)>", "TaskID")

Comment: You might simply be able to do:  Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(MyText, "Task=", "TaskID=")   That won't guarantee  it's in a tag, but if you try to do stuff within tags you may have trouble with nested tags.

Comment: I have already tried this way, it creates conflicts between other tags, that's why I want to change only between these tags mentioned in the regex..

Comment: @bobblebubble I need to replace the "Task" that is inside the tags <t1:ExecuteTask ... Task="...." > not that one

Comment: Oh, like this .NET regex: [`(?<=<t[12]:ExecuteTask[^><]+)\bTask`](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%3ct%5b12%5d%3aExecuteTask%5b%5e%3e%3c%5d%2b%29%5cbTask&i=%3ct1%3aExecuteTask+DisplayName%3d%22Normes%22+Task%3d%22932en283%22+sap%3aVirtualizedContainerService.HintSize%3d%22200%2c22%22+Parameter%3d%22Normes+tares%22+Value%3d%22%5bNormeTare%5d%22%3eTask)

Comment: @bobblebubble Oh that's almost good, I did something like this in SQL but the problem is that the word "Task" appears in the value of other tags and I don't want to change it there, your regex changes all occurrences of "Task" wherever they are..

Comment: @bobblebubble Yes I did look at this  [YourRegex](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%3ct%5b12%5d%3aExecuteTask%5b%5e%3c%5d%2b%29%5cbTask&i=%3ct1%3aExecuteTask+DisplayName%3d%22Normes%22+Task%3d%22932en283%22+sap%3aVirtualizedContainerService.HintSize%3d%22200%2c22%22+Parameter%3d%22Normes+tares%22+Value%3d%22%5bNormeTare%5d%22%3e%0d%0aTask%0d%0aTask%3e%0d%0aIt+changes+even+the+Tasks+that+are+outside+the+tags&r=TaskID)

Comment: @bobblebubble Oh sorry, I didn't notice that you updated your comment, now it works ! Can you clarify your regex by explaining please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the word `Task` can occur multiple times inside the tag, you can use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=<t[12]:ExecuteTask[^><]+)\bTask
```

- `[^><]+` [negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match one or more characters, that're not `>`, `<` for staying inside.
- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

[See demo at regexstorm](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%3Ct%5B12%5D%3AExecuteTask%5B%5E%3E%3C%5D%2B%29%5CbTask&i=%3Ct1%3AExecuteTask%20DisplayName%3D%22Normes%22%20Task%3D%22932en283%22%20sap%3AVirtualizedContainerService.HintSize%3D%22200%2C22%22%20Parameter%3D%22Normes%20tares%22%20Value%3D%22%5BNormeTare%5D%22%3ETask)

The lookbehind is a zero-width assertion which looks right before the word `Task` behind if it's preceded by one or more characters that are not `>` or `<`, preceded by `<t[12]:ExecuteTask`.

---

If you expect the word to occure only once inside, it's more efficient to use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

```
(<t[12]:ExecuteTask[^><]+?)\bTask
```

and replace with `$1TaskID` (where `$1` matches what's captured by first group).

[See another demo at regexstorm](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Ct%5B12%5D%3AExecuteTask%5B%5E%3E%3C%5D%2B%3F%29%5CbTask&i=%3Ct1%3AExecuteTask%20DisplayName%3D%22Normes%22%20Task%3D%22932en283%22%20sap%3AVirtualizedContainerService.HintSize%3D%22200%2C22%22%20Parameter%3D%22Normes%20tares%22%20Value%3D%22%5BNormeTare%5D%22%3ETask&r=%241TaskID)